# Reactstrap Input Validation Error. Help Needed

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

ReactStrap Input Validation 
Hey there! I am trying to implement validation in my form. I am using ReactStrap in my app. However, the validation isnt working for valid or invalid input. Below is what I have done. Valid ={boolean} does not give an error message (but does not work) whereas invalid gives an error message that says invalid requires a string as you can see in the error message below.

Any help is appreciated.

```
  <FormText>Valid PPSN: 7 digits followed by a letter</FormText>
            <FormFeedback valid={false}>
              You will not be able to see this
            </FormFeedback>
            <FormFeedback invalid={true}>
              You will be able to see this
            </FormFeedback>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error clearly mentioned, you need to use string for `invalid`. It's basically a message to tell why the field is invalid.

I'm not completely sure if you even need `valid`.